# JSON Data not appering in Datatable. When Clicking any function it says no data avaliable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I m using AdminBSB Material design Admin panel for a project. Im getting JSON data from an API and displaying it on a DataTable . The Data showing in the table but when i click any function sorting/searching all the data disappear from the table and showing 0 data

dataType: 'json',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {

```
    $('#loading-data3').hide();

    var i = 0;
    var count = data.total;
    console.log(count);
    for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
        $('#remaining-time').find('tbody').append(
            "<tr><td>" + data.data[i].ASSIGNEE + "</td><td>" +
            data.data[i].totalEstimateTime + "</td><td>" +
            data.data[i].timeSpent + "</td><td>" +
            data.data[i].remainTime + "</td></tr>"
        );
    }

}
```

});

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQTKB.jpg)

Comment: show the JSON output API is returning.

Comment: As you have put console.log(data); in your code, are you getting any data in the console log?

Comment: "success": true,
"code": 0,
"error": null,
"total": 55,
"data": [
  {
"ASSIGNEE": "user1",
"totalEstimateTime": "388.0000",
"timeSpent": "138.0000",
"remainTime": "250.0000"
},
  {
"ASSIGNEE": "user2",
"totalEstimateTime": "445.0000",
"timeSpent": "157.7333",
"remainTime": "287.2667"
},
]

Comment: @PiyushBansal yes we are getting the count

Comment: Remove the datatable loading code and see if that table is generated?

Comment: Can you remove the jquery that attempts to append your rows onto your datatable and console.log your elements in each loop (and produce data)? If you are able to, please post your html for the table you are appending to.

Comment: thank you. the answer below worked . looped through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using DataTables... This plugin create some new elements dynamically on every draw (caused by ordering, searches, pagination, etc). If you want to add a new row to a Datatable already instantiated, you have to use the `row.add()` method.

You should have the DataTable instantiation somewhere in your code, possibly with an option object passed as argument. If you do not yet, assign a variable to the instance.

```
var myTable = $('#remaining-time').DataTable();
```

Then when you loop through your json data to add rows, it should look like this:

```
// Your loop through json
var count = data.total;
console.log(count);
for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
  myTable.row.add([             // "myTable" refers to the Datable instance here.
    data.data[i].ASSIGNEE,
    data.data[i].totalEstimateTime,
    data.data[i].timeSpent,
    data.data[i].remainTime,
  ]);
}
```

[Documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html)